# Which template is called by WordPress

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am using WordPress and Elementor plugin. Now, I am trying to create new template for the header and footer part using Elementor Plugin.

When I click on Template -> Add New It's showing an error like that :

> "Sorry, the content area was not found in your page. You must call
> the_content function in the current template, in order for Elementor
> to work on this page."

**My question is which WordPress template file this element is called at that time?**

Answer (score 1):

I found it. It's a single.php page.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use Query Monitor WP plugin to view which pages/templates are loading in the current screen